# How to log unicode nicknames in telegram?

Tags: python, logging, unicode, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am making a telegram bot and I want to log the nicknames of those who use it.
Made it simple:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='tgbot.log', level=logging.INFO)

def log(m: Message):
    username = m.from_user.username
    logging.info(username)
```

But, if the person in the nickname has emojies, or letters from other languages, it gives me an error like this

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters. Character maps to undefined

or like this

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters. Ordinal not in range(128)

How can I fix this and log these nicknames?

---

I tried to do `logging.info(username.encode('utf-8'))` But then the byte characters like `\xe2\xad\x95` are written to the log file, but I would like to write these characters directly to the log file

Comment: About your last part: Is it not what do you want? It seems that you are using an editor which doesn't support UTF-8. Unfortunately only with Python 3.9 you can select encoding in `logging.basicConfig`

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I do not know exactly how the .encode method works, but only byte code is written to the log file, and if I selected UTF8 mode in editor, nothing changes. i am using notepad ++

Comment: Python `b'\xe2\xad\x95'.decode('utf-8')` returns `'⭕'` _Heavy Large Circle_ (codepoint `U+2B55`).

Comment: @JosefZ yes, the original string contains this character, but I want to write the same character to the log file, but in my case, for some reason, a byte code is written `b'\...'`

Comment: Use `encoding` keyword properly in [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).

Comment: @JosefZ i use python 3.7 and there is no `encoding` field in `.basicConfig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, the solution to my problem is that it's time to update python to version 3.9, but since I have 3.7 I made logging via standard stream to a file, because it is impossible to explicitly specify the encoding in the logging library

```
def log(m: Message):
    username = m.from_user.username
    f = open('bot.log', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
    f.write(username)
    f.close()
```